# Factory and non-factory design pattern differences

Tags: design-patterns

There is both an abstract and factory pattern. What exactly is the difference between these and why one be used over another?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example is given in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

An abstract factory is a "factory interface" that can be implemented by various concrete factories.

Answer (score 1):

> There is both an abstract and factory pattern.

The Gang of Four book talks about two patterns: Factory *Method*, and Abstract Factory.

A Factory method is just what it sounds like, an abstract method used to create an object:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    Foo create(); // factory method
}

public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    Foo create() {
        // the concrete type being constructed is abstracted by the factory method
        return new DerivedFoo();
    }
}
```

An abstract factory is a *type* that defines an abstraction for creating objects. In the example above, `SomeInterface` is an abstract factory.

The two are not always coupled to each other. It's perfectly valid to have a regular concrete class with some functionality that also has a factory method. An abstract factory says that the purpose of the entire class is to create one or more objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a good quick reference site for design patterns, check out http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx for examples (using C#) and brief explanations.

Also, the Head First Design Patterns book (which uses Java examples) helps break down the different patterns in an easy to understand format.

I'd recommend those 2 resources for anyone just starting to research design patterns.